# On the proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

The proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) and numerous answers were given.

Most proofs uses the idea of comparing the area of one sector and two triangle (or two sectors and one triangle) as is shown below:

[image]

My question is, how does one prove that in the graph above, the sector $ABC$ is contained in the triangle $ABD$? Namely, given any point $P$ which is contained in the sector $ABC$, how do we prove that $P$ is always contained in the triangle $ABD$?

It seems to me that in most of Calculus books, this fact is assumed as intuitively clear but never strictly proved.

Answer (score 2):

While a lot about this relies on fairly fuzzy intuition, that part at least is fairly clear. If $E$ is a point on the segment $BD$, then $AE =\sqrt{AB^2+BE^2}>AB$ by the Pythagorean theorem, and the intersection $F$ of line $AE$ with the circle lies inside the segment $AE$. Then $AF\subset  AE$ (as sets of points), and every point inside the circular wedge in that direction from $A$ is inside the triangle. Take the union over all possible $E$, and the circular wedge is a subset of the triangle.

Comment: Thanks! This is a paragraph that is missing from most calculus books.